# Passing String from C# to native C++ Library in 1256 Encoding via CLI

Tags: c#, string, encoding, c++-cli

i have to use an old C++ Library in a C# Project (.Net Framework 4).

In general i have everything set up and running but passing string values to the library is causing problems for me.

I receive string values in utf-8 containing arabic characters.
The library is handling arabic character in iso-1256 encoding.

No matter what i try i always end up with just a bunch of ??? whenever i am passing arabic strings to the library.

My approach is to convert the utf-8 encoded string to iso-1256 in the C# code and pass the result to the C++ library.

The conversion in C# looks like this:

```
var bytes = encUtf8.GetBytes((string)value);                   
String value1256 = enc1256.GetString(Encoding.Convert(encUtf8, enc1256, bytes));
```

I then proceed to pass value1256 to the library.

The CLI function called will accept a String^ sVal parameters.
The legacy code is using CString internally so i have to convert the string and here lies my problem. 
No matter how i convert the string i am ending up with just ???.

Here is a list of conversions i have tried so far, all resulting in the same output. When i check the debugger the original sVal is displayed correctly for arabic chars but every single conversion listed below results in just ???:

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(sVal);
            CString cstring6(wch);
            wchar_t* A= ( wchar_t* )( Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(sVal).ToPointer() );

            std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(sVal); 
            CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>> cStringT = CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>>( sVal );
            CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>> cStringT2 = CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>>( A );
            CString cString1 = CString( sVal );
            CString cString2 = CString(stdString.c_str());
            CString cString3 = stdString.c_str();
            CString cString4 = CString( _T( stdString.c_str() ));
            CString cString5 = CString( sVal );

            marshal_context^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
            const char* c_s = context->marshal_as<const char*>(sVal);
```

Obviously i am doing something wrong here.
Please be so kind and point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Have you tried just passing a char array with a string terminator('\0') as the last element?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `String^` object, there's only one possible encoding that it's in: UTF-16. In order to explicitly pass a different encoding around, it'll need to be a byte array, not a string.

```
enc1256.GetString(Encoding.Convert(encUtf8, enc1256, bytes));
```

You were close with this line, but not quite. You're taking the UTF-8 encoded `bytes` and converting them to a 1256 encoded byte array (good), but then converting back from that to a UTF-16 `String^` (bad). (If you look at `value1256` and your original `value`, they're probably exactly the same.) Then later, when you're doing all those conversions to various strings, they're all doing a fresh conversion from UTF-16, and they're probably all converting to ASCII or the default 1252 code page.

What I would do is to call [`Encoding::GetBytes(String^)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx), and then pass that byte array to your unmanaged C++ library. (The detour through UTF-8 is unnecessary.) Once you've switched to that encoding, try to think of it as a byte array, not a string. (I'd shy away from using any string classes, either managed or unmanaged.)

You could make the call to `GetBytes` in either C# or C++/CLI, but I'd go with C++/CLI: Let the interface that C# sees be clean & use the C# `String^` type, rather than requiring callers to know how the proper encoding.